# Jquery Datatables - Make whole row a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

This maybe simple, but cant seem to figure it out. Using jquery datatables how can I make each row clickable to just link to a normal page? So if someone moused over any of the row the whole row will hightlight and be clickable and link to whatever url I would want it to link to when clicked.

Comment: Where are you getting your URLs from?  you can build your tables with  mustache, and pass in the urls from an array ?

Comment: @Cam just building a table layout using datatables. The data is coming from a database and each row will link to a different url.

Comment: so your URL is indeed associated to the row? and you can access it as an object?

Comment: @Cam yes the url is associated to the row.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's simple enough to do this with a vanilla `<table>`, but I don't see why this wouldn't work with a jQuery DataTables one either.

```
$('#myTableId').on('click', 'tbody > tr > td', function ()
{
    // 'this' refers to the current <td>, if you need information out of it
    window.open('http://example.com');
});
```

You'll probably want some `hover` event handling there as well, to give users visual feedback before they click a row.

Comment: please don't use `.delegate()`, but use `.on('click', 'tbody > tr > td', function(){...})`

Comment: @Riki137 mind elaborating on why `delegate()` shouldn't be used? Keep in mind this answer is from 2011...

Comment: because it's not 2011 anymore

Answer (score 17):

I've use the `fnDrawCallback` parameter of the jQuery [Datatables plugin](http://datatables.net/) to make it work. Here is my solution :

```
fnDrawCallback: function () {

  $('#datatable tbody tr').click(function () {

    // get position of the selected row
    var position = table.fnGetPosition(this)

    // value of the first column (can be hidden)
    var id = table.fnGetData(position)[0]

    // redirect
    document.location.href = '?q=node/6?id=' + id
  })

}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 12):

This did it for me using the row callback.

```
fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
    responsiveHelper.createExpandIcon(nRow);
    $(nRow).click(function() {
        document.location.href = 'www.google.com';
    });
},
```

Comment: where do i put ths?

Answer (score 12):

```
$('#myTable').on( 'click', 'tbody tr', function () {
  window.location.href = $(this).data('href');
});
```

where #myTable is the ID of the table, and you need put the href in the tr, like that:

```
<tr data-href="page.php?id=1">
    <th>Student ID</th>
    <th>Fullname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Active</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: You should use data-href instead because href is not a valid attribute for a tr tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [DataTables plugins api](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api) which allows you to create custom renderers.

Answer (score 0):

Very cool: [JS addon here](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/)

And using the fnDrawCallback

```
  fnDrawCallback: function() {
    this.rowlink();
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that to make row clickable :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var oTable;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
            "ajax" : "getTable.json",
            "fnInitComplete": function ( oSettings ) {
                //On click in row, redirect to page Product of ID
                $(oTable.fnGetNodes()).click( function () {
                    var iPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
                    var aData = oSettings.aoData[ iPos ]._aData;
                    //redirect
                    document.location.href = "product?id=" + aData.id;
                } );
            },
            "columns" : [ {
                "data" : "id"
            }, {
                "data" : "date"
            }, {
                "data" : "status"
            }]
        });
    });
</script>


<table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be like that

```
$('#invoice-table').dataTable({
        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
            var slug = $(nRow).data("slug");
            $(nRow).attr("href", "/invoices/" + slug + "/");
            $(nRow).css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
            $(nRow).click(function(){
                window.location = $(this).attr('href');
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
```

And the table row like that

```
<tr class="invoice_row" data-slug="{{ invoice.slug }}">
                                <td>{{ invoice.ref }}</td>
                                <td>{{ invoice.campaign.name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ invoice.due_date|date:'d-m-Y' }}</td>
                                <td>{{ invoice.cost }}</td>
                                <td>

                                        <span class="label label-danger">Suspended</span>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
```

This worked fine with me

Answer (score 0):

**I have used a simple solution for this. Add onclick on tr and you are done. Tested with jquery datatable **

```
<tr  onclick="link(<?php echo $id; ?>)">



function link(id){
  location.href = '<?php echo $url ?>'+'/'+id;
   }
```

Comment: if you want the whole table row as link just make a function in javascript and give your url in location.href and call that function on onclick of <tr> tag the whole row will become a link. you can ask specifically where you are facing problem thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Recently I had to deal with clicking a row in datatables.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datatable tbody tr").live( 'click',function() {         
    window.open('http://www.example.com');

    } );
} );
```

Comment: please don't use .live, use .on with a decent jquery version `$("#datatable").on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {})`