# How can I select cells in Datatables .net5 web app and display the same formatting as is displayed on the default

Tags: asp.net-core, datatables, .net-5

I'm building a web app in dotnet 5, following the Pluralsight course by Scott Allen.

(here's a link to the related page by Scott https://github.com/OdeToCode/OdeToFood/blob/master/OdeToFood/OdeToFood/Pages/Restaurants/ClientRestaurants.cshtml
)

Following is a code snippet. I've replaced the references to bootstrap, jquery and Datatables with the CDN at the same version

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />

    <script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/site.js?v=4q1jwFhaPaZgr8WAUSrux6hAuh0XDg9kPS3xIVq36I0"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


        <script>
            $.ajax("/api/people/",
            { method: "get"})
            .then(function (response){
                $("#donations").DataTable({
                    data: response,
                    columns: [
                    { "data": "recId", title: "Id"},
                    { "data": "personName", title: "Name"},
                    { "data": "personAddress", title: "Address"},
                    { "data": "personCity", title: "City"},
                    { "data": "personProvince", title: "Province"}
                    ],
                    buttons: ['csv', 'excel']
                });
            });
        

        </script>

</head>
<body>
            
    <h2>Records</h2>

    <table class="table" id="mytable">

    </table>

<body>
```

The API returns rows, the DataTable populates, but I am not able to select rows or cells. I want to be able to click a row and navigate to a detail page for the record. What do I need to change to take advantage of the additional interactivity and formatting?

Mine:
[image]

Datatables Example:
[image]

Comment: If you don't want to have any links displayed in the table (as per your _"display the same formatting"_ wording - if I understood that correctly), then maybe some of the approaches in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522586/jquery-datatables-make-whole-row-a-link) may help.

Comment: @andrewjames that led me down the right path, the issue was actually the references to DataTables CDN. I had to include a few more features, including Select to get the results I wanted.
Now I'm trying to figure out how to click on the row and navigate to a details page.
Using https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html but I can't get it operational. 
Time to take a break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a self-contained demo that you can save to an HTML file and then run in a browser for yourself:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">
</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%"></table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
      dataSrc: ""
    },
    "columns": [
      { "title": "ID", "data": "id" },
      { "title": "Title", "data": "title" },
    ],
    "initComplete": function () {
      var api = this.api();
      api.$('tr').click( function () {
        var id = api.row( this ).data().id;
        var newUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + id
        window.open(newUrl); 
      } );
    }
  } );

} );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This demo uses the test JSON data made available at [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/). To start with, DataTables uses the following to load data into the HTML table:

```js
ajax: {
  method: "GET",
  url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
  dataSrc: ""
}
```

Because the JSON returned from JSONPlaceholder does not have a named array (its outer container is simply `[...]`), we need to tell DataTables about this, using `dataSrc: ""`. Your data may be structured differently.

Once the DataTable object has been initialized, we create the following function:

```js
"initComplete": function () {
  var api = this.api(); // gives us access to the DataTables API from within the table itself
  api.$('tr').click( function () { // register a row-level click event
    var id = api.row( this ).data().id; // see notes below
    var newUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + id
    window.open(newUrl); 
  } );
}
```

The following line...

```js
var id = api.row( this ).data().id;
```

...uses the DataTables API [row()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row()) call to grab the clicked row, and then find the value for the "id" field in that row. This "id" name comes from the original JSON data we loaded.

The JSONPlaceholder web site has dummy data for each "post" record. The new URL we construct takes us to that JSON record.

---

There is certainly more than one way to achieve your end goal.

In this specific case, there was no need for me to use the ["select" extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/) that you mentioned in your comments. But that is also one other approach you can use.

Comment: WOW that is just the code I need. Thank you very much. I was having a hard time placing the function (as well, I had the RenderSectionAsync('Scripts')  in the wrong part of my _Layout) to open the Details page.
Your explanation made it very clear how it works and how I could integrate it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing the configuration of the CDN for the DataTables.net CSS and JS files to include Select.

I thought that formatting was part of it by default.

[image: Screenshot of https://www.datatables.net configuration page]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.23/b-1.6.5/b-flash-1.6.5/b-html5-1.6.5/r-2.2.7/sl-1.3.1/datatables.min.css"/>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.23/b-1.6.5/b-flash-1.6.5/b-html5-1.6.5/r-2.2.7/sl-1.3.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT** While this solved my initial formatting issue, @andrewjames solved both the appearance issue and the challenge I had interacting with the DataTable.